# How to render properly Box2DDebugRenderer

Tags: libgdx

I've some problem for render Box2D Debug with Box2DDebugRenderer.
I've 2 OrthographicCamera, one for render the world (named Cam) and one for the HUD (healthBar, Armor, ...) (named hudCam).

I've tried to render :

- b2dr.render(world, cam.combined); -> I can't see the Box2D
- b2dr.render(world, cam.projection);
  [image]
- b2dr.render(world, hudCam.combined);
  [image]
- b2dr.render(world, hudCam.projection);
  [image]
- b2dr.render(world, new OrthographicCamera().combined); and b2dr.render(world, new OrthographicCamera().projection)
  [image]

I can't find a way to render the Box2D exactly like cam, to see the edge of all bodies.

If somebody understand my problem, please help me !

Thx.

Comment: Are you using a meter to pixel conversion for your sprites?

Comment: yes, and I see the potential problem ! I will look at that, thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately some tutorial out there suggest to use a meter-to-pixel-conversion when using `Box2D`. This is not neccessary (at least with Libgdx), as this conversion can be done by using a camera.
The problem in your case is, that you are using a meter-to-pixel-conversion when rendering the `Sprite`s, while the `Box2DDebugRenderer` renders everything 1:1.
To solve this problem you have to get rid of the meter-to-pixel conversion and use the `camera` or the `viewport` to "scale" the things.
THis way, the `Box2DDebugRenderer` and your `SpriteBatch` can (and should) use the same `camera` to render.

For the `camera`/`viewport`:
The constructor has the params width and height. Those params are often set as `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()`, which in my optinion is not right, the game should be resolution-independent.
You should instead select those values depending on how big your player (or any other visible entity) is in real life and how big it should be on screen.
Let's say you have a little characte, like in your game. It is 1m tall in real live and should take 1/13 of the screen height (more or less like in your first picture, where the screen is about 13 times as high as the character).
So your cameras height should be 13, your characters height (also it's `Box2D`s `Body` height) should be 1m. Next you need to define the width. For that i like to think about my desired aspect ratio. Lets assume the game should focus on 16/9 devices, the width is then `(13/9)*16=23`.
Now your camera should be created like this:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(23, 13);
```

Comment: Thx for this response !!! Very clear ! I'll try this now ! Thx U very much and Have a nice week-end :)

Comment: It's work perfectly !! But, just, how can I render that DebugBox2D in function of the gameZoom (witch change during the game) ?

Comment: You always render with the same `camera` so you only need to zoom in that camera and the DebugRenderer would render with the same zoom

Comment: @pikameuh to clarify my previous comment (and to make sure you get notified): To zoom in and out, you zoom with the `camera`. After zooming (or moving) the `camera`, you should call `camera.update()` to update it's view and projection matrix. Then you can simply `render` everything, using the `camera.combined` matrix.

Comment: Thx !! Very usefull !

Comment: Very useful answer. I was using only one camera and it was driving me crazy!